# Get GA URL pageviews with JS?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google analytics tracks pageviews.
I would like to use JavaScript to fetch the number of views that a specific page URL has.
How can I do this?

P.S. Google documentation is a mess, all I can find out from it is how to setup tracking.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Answer (score 0):

Doing this purly in javascript is going to be tricky.  Due to the fact that you will need authorization to access your data.

Now normaly for a case like this I would say use a service account but in order to use a service account to connect to google analytics, you will need to download a key file. This file must be kept save and secure.

Javascript is client side scripting how can you send a file that no one else should be allowed to access?    As far as I know there are no javascript examples for using a service account to access google analtyics i have also been unable to come up with a safe and secure way of doing this myself.  If any one has any ideas please comment i would love to hear how you got this working.

The only other option is to go with normal autentication the problem with this is that you will need to autenticate the script.  Thats not hard you could then save the RefreshToken some place and pass it to the page.  Again this is a problem anyone that then looks at your source code will have the RefreshToken and the ability to access your data.

My recomendation:  Use some server sided scripting language like php for example.

If you want to look at the code for doing this in javascript [Hello-analytics-api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api)

Comment: What if you authenticate server side and set a cookie with the token, javascript will the see the cookie and it might make it all possible? I wanted to show google analytics views (which filter bots) on some of my pages for visitors to view. If nothing works I'll do it in a small php script and have javascript fetch the count from that script.

Comment: Your idea might work, but a small php script would be simpler.